# Inno Setup parameter with quotes in [Run] section

Tags: configuration, inno-setup

I use `[Run]` section to modify the merit value of some codecs with `commandmerit.exe` that supports command-line.

So the syntax is:

```
Commandmerit.exe "{E2B7DF46-38C5-11D5-91F6-00104BDB8FF9}" "0x800000"
```

`{E2B7DF46-38C5-11D5-91F6-00104BDB8FF9}` is the CLSID of the codec and
`0x800000` is the value of the new merit, but when I put this line in `[Run]` section :

```
Filename: "{app}\Commandmerit.exe"; Parameters: ""{F8FC6C1F-DE81-41A8-90FF-0316FDD439FD}" "0x10000000""; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

The flowing error is displayed:

> Mismatched or misplaced quotes on parameter.

If I put this line:

```
Filename: "{app}\Commandmerit.exe"; Parameters: """{F8FC6C1F-DE81-41A8-90FF-0316FDD439FD}" "0x10000000"""; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

The flowing error is displayed :

> Unknown constant ...... use two consecutive"{" if .....

If I put this line:

```
Filename: "{app}\Commandmerit.exe"; Parameters: """{{F8FC6C1F-DE81-41A8-90FF-0316FDD439FD}}" "0x10000000"""; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Then no error is displayed but it seems that the `commandmerite.exe` don't understand the parameter, so after the installer finishes the merit still unchanged.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To add quotes to a parameter, you must double up each quote, and then put quotes around the entire value.

Your second attempt was close but you forgot the middle ones.

```
Filename: "{app}\Commandmerit.exe"; Parameters: """{F8FC6C1F-DE81-41A8-90FF-0316FDD439FD}"" ""0x10000000"""; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: Well that was my second guess... +1 for you, Deanna ;)

Answer (score 5):

I can see two different things in your *problem*.

First, is the `{` having a special meaning in inno setup, because it is the start of a constant. So, you have to escape the `{` by doubling it, e.g. `{{`. There is no need to escape the closing bracket because it is treated as the end of a constant only if it is a start for that constant.

Second, is that you're trying to pass `"` as part of the string, but that seems unnecessary in this case, since the purpose of the `"` character in the command line parameters is to allow the use of blank spaces inside a single parameter, but none of your parameters have spaces.

All that said, you must try writing your command like this:

```
[run]
Filename: "{app}\Commandmerit.exe"; Parameters: {{F8FC6C1F-DE81-41A8-90FF-0316FDD439FD} 0x10000000; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: thanks por reply jachguate, but the original syntax of the exe is :
Commandmerit.exe "{E2B7DF46-38C5-11D5-91F6-00104BDB8FF9}" "0x800000"

its with "{...}" ".." from the original developer of commandmerite.exe

Comment: If you need to put quotes in the parameter itself, double ALL of them: `Parameters: """{F8FC6C1F-DE81-41A8-90FF-0316FDD439FD}"" ""0x10000000""";`