# How to handle path with spaces in Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, nssm

I want to allow paths with spaces (for example `program files`) when installing my program with Inno Setup. However paths with spaces let my installed service crash.

The Inno Setup file looks like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Demo
DefaultDirName={pf}\demo

[Files]
Source: "bin\nssm.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "bin\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\*"; DestDir: "{app}\jre"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "build\libs\demo.jar"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\nssm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "install demo ""{app}\jre\bin\java.exe"" -jar ""{app}\demo.jar"""
Filename: "{app}\nssm.exe"; Parameters: "start demo"
```

"nssm.exe" is a service wrapper to execute a java application as a windows service.

The critical part is this line:

```
Filename: "{app}\nssm.exe"; \
     Parameters: "install demo ""{app}\jre\bin\java.exe"" -jar ""{app}\demo.jar"""
```

As suggested in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821436/inno-setup-parameter-with-quotes-in-run-section), I tried to use double double quotes, but this doesn't help, the service is still crashing. If I change `DefaultDirName` to a path without spaces everything works as expected.

```
DefaultDirName=c:\demo
```

How do I have to handle paths with spaces?

Comment: Your Inno Setup code it correct. Isn't the problem with your application (`nssm.exe` or `demo.jar`), rather than with the installer? Can you even run `"C:\Program Files\Demo\nssm.exe" install demo "C:\Program Files\Demo\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files\Demo\demo.jar"` from Windows command-line?

Comment: Thanks, for the hint. I tried it from the command line, but with relative paths, where it worked. The actual problem was that Inno Setup and nssm both use double quote with double quote escaping (see solution below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the combination of Inno Setup and nssm, which both are escaping double quotes with double quotes. That makes multiple double quotes necessary.

Solution:

```
Filename: "{app}\nssm.exe"; Parameters: "install demo ""{app}\jre\bin\java.exe"" -jar """"""{app}\demo.jar"""""""
```

See [nssm documentation](https://nssm.cc/usage) section "Quoting issues".

Comment: Isn't 6 `"` too much? Wouldn't 4 work? Usually the count is a power of 2, so 6 seems suspicious to me.

Comment: 4 was my second guess, but it didn't work. Sometimes I wish I simply had to deal with XML ...