# How do I pass double quotes on the parameter string in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to execute the following command in Inno Setup:

`move "MyFolder\Extra\Tesseract-OCR" "MyDestFolder"`

I tried using:

`Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: 'move ' + "MyFolder\Extra\Tesseract-OCR" + ' ' + "MyDestFolder"';`

and

`Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: 'move ' + AddQuotes(MyFolder\Extra\Tesseract-OCR) + ' ' + AddQuotes(MyDestFolder)';`

But none of them worked.

Which approach should I follow?

Comment: I got the error: *Mismatched or misplaced quotes on parameter* as expected. Here the exactly line: `Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: 'move "{app}\Extra\Tesseract-OCR" "{commonpf32}"'; StatusMsg: "Installing Tesseract OCR..."`

Comment: Ah. That's different than what you asked in your question. You should edit it to indicate exactly what you're asking. You didn't mention `{app}` or `{commonpf32}` at all in your question or in your sample code.

Comment: See [Inno Setup parameter with quotes in \[Run\] section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15821436/850848).

Answer (score 2):

Quotes can be embedded; just double them. Also, if you intend to use the `cmd.exe` `move` command, you would need the `/c` parameter. You might also consider using `/y` or as a parameter for the `move` command (depending on your needs).

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c move /y ""MyFolder\Extra\Tesseract-OCR"" ""MyDestFolder"""
```

`/y` would overwrite the file if it exists.